# Replace in FragmentTransiction cannot be applied to InfoFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to set custom animations for a transaction between two fragments, but it says that replace in the fragment transaction cannot be applied to InfoFragment(a fragment which extends Fragment), just to android.app.fragment.

```
infoFragment=InfoFragment.newInstance(latitude,longitude);
            getFragmentManager()
           .beginTransaction()
           .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in,R.animator.card_flip_right_out,R.animator.card_flip_left_in,R.animator.card_flip_left_out)
           .replace(R.id.fragment_container,infoFragment)
           .addToBackStack(null)
           .commit();
```

[image]

Comment: What does the exact error message says exactly? This is the exact code you are running (not missing any semi-colons, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're saying your InfoFragment is extending Fragment, the only thing that may be causing the issue is the fragment packages. Make sure your `InfoFragment` is importing `android.app.Fragment` only and not from the Support package.

Comment: Thx. It worked but I have a problem now. If I can't get the solution myself, I'll be back ;).

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you forgot to import infoFragment. import the package for infofragment